# Pandas: Working with Datetime using Conditional Statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please, i will need a help. I have been working on a personal project, and i got stuck.

A brief summary, i have a list called crime_list, and i want to create a new column with this list with respect to each state and province.

I also created a datetime for a specified time schedule and i want to automatically compute a new dataframe from it.

the image below explains it further. Please i need guidance and help on this

The first two images explains what i did, while the last image explained the result i wanted (i did that manually in excel, but i have a large dataset and doing it manually is not an option)

my data input:

```
data = pd.read_excel(General, 'Dap')
```

data.head()

output:

```
    State   Station
0   Abia    ekee
1   Imo dal
2   Abuja   lak
3   Kaduna  las
4   Kano    nap``
```

list  creation and datetime:

```
crime = ['Domestic Violence','Murder','Attempted murder','Total Sexual offences','Assault GBH',
     'Common Assault', 'Robbery with aggravating circumstances', 'Common Robbery']

start_date = pd.date_range('1998-04-01', '2019-03-01', freq='MS')
end_date = pd.date_range('1998-04-30', '2019-03-31', freq='M')
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1998-04-30', '1998-05-31', '1998-06-30', '1998-07-31',
           '1998-08-31', '1998-09-30', '1998-10-31', '1998-11-30',
           '1998-12-31', '1999-01-31',
           ...
           '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30',
           '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-31',
           '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=252, freq='M')
```

My code:

```
for crim in crime_list:
    for stat in data['Station']:
        data['Crime list'] = pd.Series(crim)
        data['Start Date'] = pd.Series(start_date)
        data['End Date'] = pd.Series(end_date)
```

output:

```
        State   Station Crime list  Start Date  End Date
0   Abia    ekee    Shoplifting 1998-04-01  1998-04-30
1   Imo dal NaN 1998-05-01  1998-05-31
2   Abuja   lak NaN 1998-06-01  1998-06-30
3   Kaduna  las NaN 1998-07-01  1998-07-31
4   Kano    nap NaN 1998-08-01  1998-08-31
5   Enugu   nak NaN 1998-09-01  1998-09-30
6   Lagos   laj NaN 1998-10-01  1998-10-31
```

Desired Output:

```
State   Station crime   start date  end date
0   Abia    ekee    Domestic Violence   1998-04-01  1998-04-30
1   Abia    ekee    Domestic Violence   1998-05-01  1998-05-31
2   Abia    ekee    Domestic Violence   1998-06-01  1998-06-30
3   Abia    ekee    Domestic Violence   1998-07-01  1998-07-31
4   Abia    ekee    Murder  1998-04-01  1998-04-30
```

Comment: Hi, still not sure, what you want to do. Why does your desired output only display one state? are you only interested in this one state? Your loop assignes the same values again for each iteration of the inner loop without changeing anything. Do you maybe intend to create a list which contains one row per date, crime type and station? If so, I guess you could look for a solution using merge.

Comment: @jottbe Thank you for responding. I want my desired output to display each crime in the list with respect to dates from (1998-2019). The desired output will have each state with different crimes(ranging from dates from 1998-2019). I can share the code with you if you want.

Comment: I want to create a list with states, with each station reporting each crime with the date range(1998-2019) @jottbe

Comment: The desired output is meant to display all the states with each crime type and date range(from 1998-2019)... @jottbe

Comment: @jottbe how can i use the merge function to do that?

Comment: @waitingkuo  Please can you help me out?

Comment: @viddik13 Please can you help out?

Comment: @cs95 Please can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to produce a dataframe which contains all combination of the three data parts (state/stagen, start/end and crime type), to fill in values in that frame later, you can do that as follows.

Not sure if that is, what you were searching for.

You could do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# if I understood correctly, your read your data from an excel with two
# columns State and Station, you can just replace the following line by
# your read_csv
data= pd.DataFrame(dict(State=['Abia', 'Imo', 'Abuja', 'Kaduna', 'Kano'], Station=['ekee', 'dal', 'lak', 'las', 'nap']))
crime = ['Domestic Violence','Murder','Attempted murder','Total Sexual offences','Assault GBH', 'Common Assault', 'Robbery with aggravating circumstances', 'Common Robbery']

# create a fake dataframe for the crime types
df_crime= pd.DataFrame(dict(crime=crime))

# create a fake dataframe for the start- and enddate
start_date = pd.date_range('1998-04-01', '2019-03-01', freq='MS')
end_date = pd.date_range('1998-04-30', '2019-03-31', freq='M')
df_date= pd.DataFrame(dict(start=start_date, end=end_date))

# add fake join columns to produce a cross-prodct of all three
data['fake_join']= 1
df_crime['fake_join']= 1
df_date['fake_join']= 1

# now merge the three data frames and remove the fake join column
df_result= data.merge(df_date, on='fake_join')
df_result= df_result.merge(df_crime, on='fake_join')
df_result.drop(columns=['fake_join'])

# let's check the output
df_result.sort_values(['start', 'Station']).head(20)

      State Station  ...        end                                   crime
2016    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                       Domestic Violence
2017    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                                  Murder
2018    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                        Attempted murder
2019    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                   Total Sexual offences
2020    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                             Assault GBH
2021    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                          Common Assault
2022    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30  Robbery with aggravating circumstances
2023    Imo     dal  ... 1998-04-30                          Common Robbery
0      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                       Domestic Violence
1      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                                  Murder
2      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                        Attempted murder
3      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                   Total Sexual offences
4      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                             Assault GBH
5      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                          Common Assault
6      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30  Robbery with aggravating circumstances
7      Abia    ekee  ... 1998-04-30                          Common Robbery
4032  Abuja     lak  ... 1998-04-30                       Domestic Violence
4033  Abuja     lak  ... 1998-04-30                                  Murder
4034  Abuja     lak  ... 1998-04-30                        Attempted murder
4035  Abuja     lak  ... 1998-04-30                   Total Sexual offences

[20 rows x 6 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs a bit of clarification, but from what I think, you want to repeatedly map crimes to provinces and stations, for the range of the dates you have.

So:
State | Station | Start Date | End Date | Crime Category |
where station repeats for the list of crimes within the range of date. I'm not sure I have not ended up making it more complex, but if I'm right, then check out this snippet:

```py
result = []

for (s_index, station) in enumerate(stations):
    for crime in crimes[:len(start_dates)]:
        for (d_index, start_date) in enumerate(start_dates):
            result.append([states[s_index], station, start_date, end_dates[d_index], crime])

ds = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['State', 'Stations', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Crime Category'])
ds.head()
```

```
    Province    Stations    Start Date  End Date    Crime Category
Eastern Cape    Aberdeen    2019-01-01  2019-01-31  Domestic Violence
Eastern Cape    Aberdeen    2019-02-01  2019-02-28  Domestic Violence
Eastern Cape    Aberdeen    2019-03-01  2019-03-31  Domestic Violence
Eastern Cape    Aberdeen    2019-04-01  2019-04-30  Domestic Violence
Eastern Cape    Aberdeen    2019-05-01  2019-05-31  Domestic Violence
```

```py
ds.tail()
```

```
    Province    Stations    Start Date  End Date    Crime Category
Western Cape    Wynberg 2019-02-01  2019-02-28  Common Assault
Western Cape    Wynberg 2019-03-01  2019-03-31  Common Assault
Western Cape    Wynberg 2019-04-01  2019-04-30  Common Assault
Western Cape    Wynberg 2019-05-01  2019-05-31  Common Assault
Western Cape    Wynberg 2019-06-01  2019-06-30  Common Assault
```